# Javascript change input field color

Tags: javascript

i have this code(works fine) that changes the color of all fields wheather the field is empty or not:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((inp) => {
  inp.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
    let value = inp.value.split(" ").join("");
    if (value == "") inp.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    else inp.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  });
});
```

Now i want to validate the first name field, it should only be able to input letters. If it is wrong, i want it to show it as red. i tried with the following code but it doesnt work. Any ideas?

```
let firstName = document.querySelector("#fname");
firstName.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
  if (typeof firstName.value != "string") {
    firstName.value.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    console.log(firstName.value);
  } else {
    firstName.value.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
});
```

Comment: The value will _always_ be a string, even if it's an empty one.

Comment: even when i input a number it doesnt work

Comment: Because the _value_ will _always_ be a _string_, even if it's a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` will *always* be a string so you should test what characters the string contains instead, and you can do this with a regular expression that tests that it only contains letters from the alphabet.

```js
let firstName = document.querySelector("#fname");

firstName.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
  if (!/[a-zA-Z]+/.test(firstName.value)) {
    firstName.style.backgroundColor = "#FF374E";
  } else {
    firstName.style.backgroundColor = "#c0eb34";
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="fname" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Regex to check if string has number. Something like:

```
let firstName = document.querySelector("#fname");
firstName.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
  let hasNumber = /\d/; 
  if (hasNumber.test(firstName.value)) {
    firstName.value.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    console.log(firstName.value);
  } else {
    firstName.value.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
});
```